# Notificação com fundo cinza?

Tags: android

As notificações que gero aparecem com fundo cinza o que dificulta a leitura da noticia:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker("Ticker Texto");
    builder.setContentTitle(" notificação");
    builder.setContentText("Você tem uma nova notícia");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icone);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icone));
    builder.setContentIntent(p);
    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
...
```

porque esta aparecendo cinza o fundo?

Comment: Mostra uma imagem do que se esta a passar.

Comment: Mas o que deve estar a acontecer é o fundo por defeito ser cinzento.

Comment: Dá um saque aqui nesse link: http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/custom-notifications-background-color.html

Comment: Dante alterei o sdk pra 9, e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que cinzento é a cor por defeito do `NotificationCompat`.

Podes alterar a cor assim:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
builder.setLights(Color.White, 500, 500);
builder.defaults = 0;
```

[Referência SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18763753/1817673)